# How to put a datetime value into a numpy array?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, python-datetime

I am learning python so please bear with me.  I have been trying to get a datetime 
variable into a numpy array, but have not been able to figure out how.  I need to calculate differences between times for each index later on, so I didn't know if I should put the datetime variable into the array, or convert it to another data type.  I get the error:

```
'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Is my dtype variable constructed correctly? [This](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) says nothing about datetime type.

```
import numpy as np
from liblas import file

f = file.File(project_file, mode = 'r')
num_points = int(f.__len())
# dtype should be [float, float, float, int, int, datetime]
dt = [('x', 'f4'), ('y', 'f4'), ('z', 'f4'), ('i', 'u2'), ('c', 'u1'), ('time', 'datetime64')]
xyzict = np.empty(shape=(num_points, 6), dtype = dt)

# Load all points into numpy array
counter = 0
for p in f:
    newrow = [p.x, p.y, p.z, p.i, p.c, p.time]
    xyzict[counter] = newrow     
    counter += 1
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I should note that I plan on sorting the array by date before proceeding.

p.time is in the following format:

```
>>>p.time
datetime.datetime(1971, 6, 26, 19, 37, 12, 713269)
>>>str(p.time)
'1971-06-26 19:37:12.713275'
```

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of `project_file` for us to see?  There is likely a much better way of going about this, but it depends on how the dates are formatted, among other things.

Comment: project_file is actually an LAS file.  I assumed there was a better way.  If it helps I will edit my post with p.time.

Comment: Oh, that edit helps: try using `'datetime64[us]'` as your dtype.

Comment: Line 14 gives me the error TypeError: expected a readable buffer object

Comment: Oh, for that try making `newrow` a tuple instead of list.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? You're getting a `None` value from somewhere, it seems, but it's not clear to me where the exception is happening.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#98>", line 3, in <module>
    xyzict[counter] = newrow
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand how you are getting a `datetime` object out of your file, or what `p` is for that matter, but assuming you have a list of tuples (not lists, see my comment above), you can do the setting all in one step:

```
dat = [(.5, .5, .5, 0, 34, datetime.datetime(1971, 6, 26, 19, 37, 12, 713269)),
       (.3, .3, .6, 1, 23, datetime.datetime(1971, 6, 26, 19, 34, 23, 345293))]

dt = [('x', 'f4'), ('y', 'f4'), ('z', 'f4'), ('i', 'u2'), ('c', 'u1'), ('time', 'datetime64[us]')]

datarr = np.array(dat, dt)
```

Then you can access the fields by name:

```
>>> datarr['time']
array(['1971-06-26T15:37:12.713269-0400', '1971-06-26T15:34:23.345293-0400'], dtype='datetime64[us]')
```

Or sort by field:

```
>>> np.sort(datarr, order='time')
array([ (0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 1, 23, datetime.datetime(1971, 6, 26, 19, 34, 23, 345293)),
        (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 34, datetime.datetime(1971, 6, 26, 19, 37, 12, 713269))], 
  dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'), ('i', '<u2'), ('c', 'u1'), ('time', '<M8[us]')])
```

Comment: if i make newrow a tuple, each array index contains 6 duplicates of the data.  Should I change the shape of the empty array to shape=(num_points, 1)?

Comment: Yeah that should work. Actually make the shape `(num_points,)` without the one.  A structured array is 1d.  The "columns" are "fields", and the elements are tuples.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  That works perfectly.  If i could ask, since you showed me how to sort, how would I iterate through the array, getting the time field value?

Comment: As you see in the answer, you can get all the times using `datarr['time']`. If you want to do something to all of them, don't iterate through them, just apply it to the entire array.  If you do want to iterate, you can still do `for t in datarr['time']: ...` as you would with any list or array.

Comment: Great, thanks again.  I found np.nditer(xyzict) does what I want.